# organize the order of element and push the total of sub-array

Tags: php

```
 $base_arr =   Array
  (
      1 => Array
          (
          0 => 1,
          1 => 2,
          2 => 5,
          3 => 5
          ),
      3 => Array
          (
          0 => 1,
          1 => 2
          ),
      7 => Array
          (
          0 => 1,
          1 => 4
          )
   );
```

I want to re organize the order of element and push the total of sub-array to the main array.the result I want to return like this:

```
 $new_arr =   Array(
     0 => 1,
     1 => 2,
     2 => 5,
     3 => 5,
     4 =>13, //this is the total 1+2+5+5 = 13
     5 => 1,
     6 => 2,
     7 => 3,//this is the total 1+2 = 3
     8 => 1,
     9 => 4,
     10 =>5 //this is the total 1+4 = 5

   );
```

Who can help me please ,thanks.

Comment: How would you use that new array? Doing it like that, if you modify the $new_arr, say adding a new element, it would be messy to keep track of totals and elements of each base array. Could you not use an assoc array to label $new_arr? Then you could access totals as $new_arr[1]['total']

Comment: i agree with AJweb, if you dont know that $new_arr[4] is a totale amount or not. but if you using for every totale a $new_arr['totale']
you dont know anymore which one u wanna have:
the first totale with 13
or the second totale with 3
or the third totale with 5

Comment: the new array I will use for paganation($new_arr,$page) with the $show_per_page defined.

Comment: @Ajweb,Tricker,Both of you have any idea?thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good chance to try closures in PHP 5.3:

```
   $new = array();

   array_walk($base_arr, function ($item) use (&$new) {
               $new = array_merge($new, $item);
               $new []= array_sum($item);
            }
    );

    var_dump($new);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the result you want:

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($base_arr as $base)
{
    $count = 0; //Reset in begin of the loop (with 0)
    foreach($base as $child) 
    {
        $count += $child; //Count the values
        $new_arr[] = $child;
    }
    $new_arr[] = $count; //Put totale in the array
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using array functions:

```
$new=array();
foreach ($base_arr as $bb) {
  $new=array_merge($new, $bb);
  array_push($new, array_sum($bb));
}
```